# Emulating smart card

Tags: python, emulation, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I have to make an app for a university project, we have to make a distributed transaction system, and it has to work with smart cards, in order to test it we were told to use an emulator ( personal language preference is python ), anyone has an idea about what to do next ? after some research i've come up with these results, but there isn't much to go on with.

The python library to use is : [pyscard](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscard)

two emulators i found, but as i said, not much to go on with :

[Virtual Smart Card Emulator](https://sourceforge.net/p/vsmartcard)

i'm running ubuntu 12.04 & i might consider java for the apps

i hope someone can clarify things a little bit more for me, thanks

Comment: http://www.openscdp.org/
   http://jcardsim.org/
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821915/is-there-a-free-virtual-smartcard-which-i-could-use-to-run-some-tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the SmartCard stuff in J2ME, which comes with a simulator:
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0-win/html-helpset/z400008e37797.html

Comment: Thanks, i ended up going with the javacard's CREF